# find out the list of partitions and %of use

Tags: linux

This is the output of `df -h`:

[image]

I need `Filesystem`, `Use%` and `Mounted on` columns written to a file.
I tried `df -h | awk -F" " '{print $5,$6)'` but it gives the output as shown below and it is not the correct info.

```
/
1% /dev/shm
21% /boot
1% /boot/efi

/home

/tmp

/usr

/usr/local

/var/log

/var/tmp

/opt
98% /Prod_D/data1
98% /Prod_D/data2
98% /Prod_D/data3
98% /Prod_D/data4
98% /Prod_D/data5
98% /Prod_D/data6
98% /Prod_D/data7
98% /Prod_D/data8
97% /Prod_D/data9

/Prod_D/data10
```

So, how do I do it?

Comment: Please, provide **textual** output of the command, which you want to parse. In the textual output we can distinguish spaces with other non-printable characters, and correctly see newlines, which are important for using `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `df` version at hand wraps output lines with long filesystem pathnames. Use the option `-P` (POSIX output format) to avoid that:

```
df -hP | awk '{print $1,$5,$6}'
```